# What statistical test can I use to show the following hypothesis?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have two user groups A and B.

I want to see the difference in the effect between A and B when a condition is given compared to the condition being not given.

If the sample of condition given and not given is the same, I would simply subtract the evaluation metric and compare them using t-test.

However, they're not.
In this case, what statistical test should I use?

To be specific, I have two user groups A and B. Half of each user groups will be shown caption and half will not be shown caption while watching a video.

I want to compare how much the user experience will be different between user groups A and B.

My hypothesis is: Compared to when caption is given, when caption is not given, the user experience will drop more significantly for user group A compared to user group B.

I'm trying to see this by recruiting user groups A and B and showing them one random video among many videos.

In this case, what statistical test should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you might have a situation where a two-way analysis of variance might be applied.  ... However, if you are using the same video for some participants, you might want to include *Which Video* in the model as well.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you! You mean Two-way ANOVA right? How should I include Which Video in the model as well? Should I use three-way ANOVA?

Comment: You say: "*Compared to when caption is given, when caption is not given, the user experience will drop more significantly for user group A compared to user group B.*" ... **1**. If you mean 'significantly' in the statistical sense: a hypothesis is a statement about population parameters. The word "significant" is a property of a *sample* statistic (specifically whether a test statistic falls into a predetermined rejection region) and has *no place whatever in a hypothesis*. **2**. If you *don't* mean 'significantly' in the statistical sense, you need to make the intended meaning explicit.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for pointing that out! I didn't know about it. What I tried to mean is "Compared to when caption is given, when caption is not given, the user experience will drop more for user group A compared to user group B." Please let me know if there's any more errors in the hypothesis!

Comment: That seems fine for a research hypothesis. It should convert into an alternative hypothesis without problems.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you! Considering SalMangiafico's advice, I'm thinking of using two-way ANOVA. But I'm not sure how to take into account 'which video' in this case. Can you give me any idea on this?